# How do I expand the table on the next page when the previous page is full?

Tags: tables, longtable, fontsize

I have a problem with the use of LaTeX tables because they are on more than one page, although the maximum number of pages is two. Moreover, the spacing between the rows is big. How can I adjust this? And how can I get the table to move to the next page when the previous page is full without any spacing?

[image]

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
 \begin{longtable}{|C{2cm}|C{2.5cm}|C{3cm}|C{2cm}|C{5cm}|}
 \caption{Summarizing deep learning for medical image classification}
 \label{table:ex1} \\
  \hline
   Reference & Model & Domain & Objectives & The best result of performance metrics \\
   \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{5}{c}%
     {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
      \hline
       Reference & Model & Domain & Objectives & The best result of performance metrics 
       \\
        \hline
         \endhead
           \hline \multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
            \endfoot
              \hline
              \endlastfoot
         \cite{sarwinda2021deep} & ResNet-18, ResNet-50 & Gastroenterology & The models 
         were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The 
         highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\ \hline  \cite{sarwinda2021deep} & 
          ResNet-18, ResNet-50 & Gastroenterology & The models 
         were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The 
         highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\ \hline\cite{sarwinda2021deep} & 
          ResNet-18, ResNet-50 & Gastroenterology & The models 
         were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The 
         highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\ \hline\cite{sarwinda2021deep} & 
         ResNet-18, ResNet-50 & Gastroenterology & The models 
         were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The 
         highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\ \hline\cite{sarwinda2021deep} & 
          ResNet-18, ResNet-50 & Gastroenterology & The models 
         were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The 
         highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\ \hline\cite{sarwinda2021deep} & 
          ResNet-18, ResNet-50 & Gastroenterology & The models 
         were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The 
         highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\ \hline
              \end{longtable}
```

**Note:** There is duplication of content in the table in question here.

Comment: I would first try using a normal tabular or tabularx in a table [htp] and only use longtable when that doesn't work.

Comment: It might be possible to create a macro or environ (environ package) to measuire if a tabular would fit in one page, then switch to longtable.  One could store the caption globally and disable things like `\endfirsthead`.

Comment: Any news? Does any of received answer solve your problem? If does, please consider to accept it (the best one) by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer!

Comment: Please show your document set-up by providing a minimal working example. Only then it is possible to tell why you got such a large line spacing inside the table cells. But it is better to only ask one question at a time on this site anyways.

Answer (score 2):

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small complete document, which we can compiles it is.
- The sum of the given columns width exceed default size of the `\textwidth` when `article` document class is used.

Solution with use of the `longtblr` of `tabularray` package, where are considered:

- page layout is defined by `geometry` package
- the last two columns have the same width (2.3 times wider than first two columns)
- for aligning text in cell in the last two columns is used `ragged2e` package
- also is used `microtype` package for better inter word spacing of text
- for better text spacing of text in cells is reduced font size in table (to `\small`)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot}{font=\footnotesize\itshape}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Summarizing deep learning for medical image classification},
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                 cells = {font=\small},
                 colspec = { *{2}{X[c]} c *{3}{X[2.3, j, cmd={\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}]} },
                 colsep  = 3pt,
                 row{1}  = {cmd={\Centering}, m},
                 rowhead = 1
                 }
% column headers
Reference & Model & Domain & Objectives & The best result of performance metrics \\
% table body
\cite{sarwinda2021deep} 
    & ResNet-18, ResNet-50  & Gastroenterology & The models were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\
\cite{sarwinda2021deep}
    & ResNet-18, ResNet-50  & Gastroenterology & The models were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\
\cite{sarwinda2021deep}
    & ResNet-18, ResNet-50  & Gastroenterology & The models were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\
\cite{sarwinda2021deep}
    & ResNet-18, ResNet-50  & Gastroenterology & The models were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\
\cite{sarwinda2021deep}
    & ResNet-18, ResNet-50  & Gastroenterology & The models were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\
\cite{sarwinda2021deep}
    & ResNet-18, ResNet-50  & Gastroenterology & The models were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\
\cite{sarwinda2021deep}
    & ResNet-18, ResNet-50  & Gastroenterology & The models were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\
\cite{sarwinda2021deep}
    & ResNet-18, ResNet-50  & Gastroenterology & The models were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\
\cite{sarwinda2021deep}
    & ResNet-18, ResNet-50  & Gastroenterology & The models were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\
\cite{sarwinda2021deep}
    & ResNet-18, ResNet-50  & Gastroenterology & The models were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\
\cite{sarwinda2021deep}
    & ResNet-18, ResNet-50  & Gastroenterology & The models were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\
\cite{sarwinda2021deep}
    & ResNet-18, ResNet-50  & Gastroenterology & The models were able to differentiate between benign and malignant colorectal cancer & The highest accuracy achieved by ResNet-50 \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Answer (score 0):

From the get go, if your only issue is the table height, you can try changing this particular line…

```latex
\begin{longtable}{|C{2cm}|C{2.5cm}|C{3cm}|C{2cm}|C{5cm}|}
```

Into something like this!

```latex
\begin{longtable}{|C{2.5cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|}
```

Since, because how the column type “`C`” is defined on your first line, on every `C{x}`, `x` controls the width of the text box for each column. If your project requires a total length of 14.5cm, you can use the line I posted earlier. But the gist of it is to modify those values so the longer text has more horizontal space available!

Also, do you need to use the `tabularx` and `longtable` packages for this document? You could take a look at the `tabularray` package since it gives you a bit more of control on your tables.

Finally, keep in mind that tables defined as “long tables” will always break a page when possible. If you want to prevent this, use in your example the `tabularx` environment.

Comment: ok it is work now , but how i can adjust size between line inside table ? and how make all table in centre @Manan Intindinichu

Comment: @BoushraAliAL-Shehri You mean the whitespace between text and line on each column? Or the width of the divisor line? The earlier can be done by modifying `\tabcolsep`, and the later with `\arrayrulewidth`. By default, those values are respectively 6pt and 0.4pt, so writing, for example, `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt} \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}` will give you a thinner whitespace and wider lines.

If I got time, I’ll try to update the solution to show a couple of examples on how to do this and some alternatives.